# Problem with getting libconfig's cflags

Tags: apt, pkg-config

I'm trying to compile a C project that uses libconfig. I've installed `libconfig8-dev` package and I'm trying to retrieve the c flags required to compile the project. Running `pkg-config --libs libconfig` works as expected, however `pkg-config --cflags libconfig`, returns nothing. Also, there is no `libconfig.pc` file inside `/usr/lib/pkgconfig/`. My make file goes as follows:

```
TARGET = uartIO

CFLAGS = -Wall -I. -pthread `pkg-config --cflags libconfig`

LFLAGS = -Wall -I. -pthread 
LDLIBS = `pkg-config --libs libconfig`

SRCDIR   = src
OBJDIR   = obj
BINDIR   = bin

SOURCES  := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.c)
INCLUDES := $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.h)
OBJECTS  := $(SOURCES:$(SRCDIR)/%.c=$(OBJDIR)/%.o)
rm       = rm -f

debug: CFLAGS += -g
debug: $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)

$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LFLAGS) $(LDLIBS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@
    @echo "Linking complete!" 

$(OBJECTS): $(OBJDIR)/%.o : $(SRCDIR)/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
    @echo "Compiled "$<" successfully!"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(rm) $(OBJECTS)
    @echo "Cleanup complete!"

.PHONY: remove
remove: clean
    @$(rm) $(BINDIR)/$(TARGET)
    @echo "Removal complete!"
```

Compiling results in various errors about undefined functions from e.g `undefined reference to 'config_init'`.

Comment: It's not unusual for `pkg-config --cflags` to return nothing: it just means that no additional flags are required (for example, all the required header files are on the standard include path). The `.pc` file likely goes in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/`. **What actual compilation issue are you having?**

Comment: @steeldriver edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will likely find the `.pc` file in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/`

It's not unusual for `pkg-config --cflags` to return nothing: it just means that no additional flags are required (for example, all the required header files are on the standard include path).

In any case, `CFLAGS` relate to the *compile phase* of a build, not the *link phase* - which is where undefined symbol errors occur.

Your issue is likely that you are linking the libraries and object files in the wrong order: see for example [Why does the order of '-l' option in gcc matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11893996/why-does-the-order-of-l-option-in-gcc-matter) So try

```
$(BINDIR)/$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(OBJECTS) $(LFLAGS) $(LDLIBS)
    @echo "Linking complete!"
```

Also, it doesn't make sense to specify an include path during the link phase; if you need to link libraries from the current directory, then replace

```
LFLAGS = -Wall -I. -pthread
```

by

```
LFLAGS = -Wall -L. -pthread
```

(although TBH I'm not sure that `-Wall` has any effect during the link phase).